# Swap Values in MIPS assembly

Tags: algorithm, assembly, mips, mips32, mars-simulator

I am new to MIPS and am currently stuck on how to swap values in my stack allocated array.

Here are the registers I am working with and the values being stored in them:

$t3 - Stores the address of array[j]

$t5 - Stores the address of array[j+1]

$t4 - Stores the Value at array[j]

$t6 - Stores the Value at array[j+1]

I am having trouble figuring out how to use these registers and their values in order to swap them.

*Using MARS simulator 4.5 32 bit*

**Goal**:

I want to store $t6 value into the memory location stored in register $t3.

I want to store $t4 value into the memory location stored in register $t5

I have tried numerous different solutions of my own and various samples from the internet and I just cannot seem to get it working.

I have tried using sw instructions to store the values into the address but It does not appear to work but i have a feeling this may stem from my personal confusion on using registers/address/memory/value when executing these instructions.

Here is what I believe is the relevant portion of my code needed.

```
    lw $t4, ($t3) # get Value from memory address in $t3 and load it into $t4 register 
    lw $t6, ($t5) # get Value from memory address in $t5 and load it into $t6 register
    
    bgt $t4,$t6,swap # is the first number bigger than the second? if so, branch to swap
    
    j swapdone
      
swap:

    # Swap Values here

    sw $t4, ($t5) # store $t4 value at the address stored in $t5
    sw $t6, ($t3) # store $t6 value at the address stored in $t3
   
    j swapdone

swapdone:
```

Comment: That looks correct (you don't need the `j swapdone` of course but it's harmless).

Comment: This part looks to me like it'll work.  The branching is overcomplicated, you just need one conditional branch to skip the stores, no `j` instructions.  (Don't `b` over a `j`, just use the opposite condition in the branch, like `ble $t4, $t6, swapdone` (or rename that label to `noswap`).  If your program using this code isn't working, the problem is elsewhere and this isn't a [mcve].  Use the debugger built-in to MARS and look at registers and memory as you single-step through a case where the swap should or shouldn't happen.  (And through other parts of your program).

Comment: Thanks to the both of you. This solution did in fact work and my problem was located elsewhere (within the nested loops control flow surrounding this piece of code). Thanks to your advice I cleaned up my branching while paying more careful attention  to it and it now works great! Also I appreciate the link to the minimal reproducible example, I will definitely be following that from here on out as it would have been extremely applicable here as you mentioned. Thanks!